# Extract, create and append using xpath and telegram instant view

Tags: xpath, telegram, xpath-1.0, instant-view

```
<iframe src="https://expmle.com/subdirectory/sample_title" />
```

How can I **create** and **append** below `<a>` tag from above code using `XPath` and [Telegram Instant view](https://instantview.telegram.org/docs) functions?

```
<a href="https://expmle.com/subdirectory/sample_title">sample_title</a>
```

I want to extract whole `src` and **last part** of that and use of them to create `<a>` tag.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work correctly.

```
<a>: //iframe # Find iframe and convert it to <a>

@set_attr(href, ./@src) # Set href attribute from src

$anchor # Create variable for current <a>
@set_attr(text, ./@href) # We set new attribute for link which will processed by @match function, then @text attribute will be replaced by result of the @match
@match("\\w+_\\w+"): $@/@text # Now we find our future name of the link "sample_name" (this function will replace all in @text by our new name

@prepend(@text): $anchor # And then put this name to his $anchor
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it almost worked except the last line. `$@` is an attribute node and I don't know why but `@prepend_to` didn't add it as a text of `<a>`.

Comment: I was trying to use `@prepend($@): $anchor` but it parses `$@` as a string not a variable :(   What do you think?

Comment: Thanks, I needed to change `$@/@text` to `$$/@text` or `$anchor/@text` to get result.

Comment: Cool! Good luck in the contest :)

Answer (score 1):

```java
# append <a> tag below
@after(<a>, href, ./@src, content, ./@src): //iframe

# take everything after the last slash
@match("[^\/]+$", "1"): $@/@content

# move the attribute inside the tag
@append(@content): $@
```

If the last `$@` won't work, just define a variable for `<a>`.

Comment: Thank you very much, yep as you told I needed to define a variable for `<a>`, Also I changed your regex to `"[^\/]+$"` and remove dot-slash(`./`) from `@append(./@content)` and now it works fine.

Comment: @Alizadeh118 Could you change the best answer then?